# NIntegrate failed to perform the integration unless AdaptiveMonteCarlo method is chosen

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have multi-dimensional numerical integration of some function depending on one parameter. If no specification for the integration method is chosen, the output for specific values of the parameters is just the text form of the integration command: `NIntegrate[f[x,y,z],{x,x0,x1},{y,y0,y1},{z,z0,z1}]`. However, when I chose `AdaptiveMonteCarlo` method, the output is reasonable number.

Is there any option or parameter of NIntegrate command which allows the integration to be performed without setting the Method to AdaptiveMonteCarlo (probably, by using the other methods)? It gives relatively large uncertainty which is likely to be avoided.

P.S. Unfortunately, the function I used has rather long definition, and it would be problematic to write it here as an example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Just evaluate `SetOptions[NIntegrate, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]` before anything else if you prefer that that method be used automatically.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay : but this method contains relatively large uncertainty in comparison to other integration methods, and I would like to avoid it. I'm wondering why other methods don't work.

Comment: You asked "Is there any option of NIntegrate which allows the integration to be performed without setting the specific method?", while that one in your comment is a different question altogether.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. : This is really so. I've updated my question.